# What is the proper way to format "is_a? Integer"?

Tags: ruby, integer

I'm trying to use the code below to keep a value in the hash only if the key is an integer. What am I doing wrong here?

```
hackerrank.keep_if do |x,y| x.is_a? Integer end
```

EDIT: I must be doing something wrong because I keep getting a Runtime error on HackerRank.com. My full code is as follows:

```
hackerrank.store[543121,100] # store new key-value pair
hackerrank.keep_if { |x,y| x.is_a?(Integer) } # keep if key is an integer
hackerrank.delete_if { |x,y| x % 2 == 0 } # delete if key is even
```

EDIT 2: Link to the challenge is available here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ruby-hash-add-del-sel

Comment: It's correct, but instead of do.....end, you can use block({}).

Comment: I wanna ask that whether hackerrank is a Hash?If it is ,why it has method like store[54321, 100] , because I can't call something like this

Comment: Yes, HackerRank is a hash @ShallmentMo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
    hackerrank[543121] = 100 # store new key-value pair
    hackerrank.keep_if { |x,y| x.is_a?(Integer) && x.odd? } # keep if key is an integer and not even
```

Or try, your code by using @seph's suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/31018495/2545197 -

```
 hackerrank.store(543121,100) # store new key-value pair
 hackerrank.keep_if { |x,y| x.is_a?(Integer) } # keep if key is an integer
 hackerrank.delete_if { |x,y| x % 2 == 0 } # delete if key is even
```

Comment: Bingo!! Thank you :) I'm guessing the compiler didn't like my syntax?

Comment: @Amit Suroliya : You can also do `x.even?` instead `x % 2 != 0`

Comment: @GaganGami Yes, we can.

Comment: @GaganGami Very cool.. any reason it's not ".is_even?" instead of ".even?"

Comment: @Shawn : there is not such method `.is_even?` you can check about `.even?` here http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F

Comment: @Shawn There is a reason here why `.is_even?` doesn't exists, cause if you go by words `.is_even?` doesn't require second parameter to be passed in order to check whether input is even or not . where as if you see how `.is_a` works, it says "It Returns `true` if `class` is the `class` of `obj`, or if `class` is one of the `superclasses` of `obj` or `modules` included in `obj`." which does require it to compare with other obj.

Comment: Thank you for that in-depth explanation @Abhinay!

Comment: @AmitSuroliya No issues here but when you update your answer by seeing some one else's suggestion like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/31018495/2545197 , you should just mention it gracefully.

Comment: @AmitSuroliya Was talking about mentioning it in your updated answer. but thats completely your choice.

Comment: @AmitSuroliya appreciate that :+1

Answer (score 3):

It needs to look like this(parentheses, not square brackets):

```
hackerrank.store(543121, 100)
#=> 100
```

Comment: This solution is much better!!

Comment: Bingo, this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

```
# store expects two parameters, let‘s
#                ⇓ splat an array
hackerrank.store *[543121, 100]
# let’s select everything we are interested in
#        inplace ⇓     only integers ⇓⇓⇓  odds  ⇓⇓⇓⇓
hackerrank.select! { |(k,v)| Integer === k && k.odd? }
```

Comment: This works opposite, don't you think so ?.. k.even? could solve this

Comment: Yes, my bad.misunderstood the question